# How can I set icon size in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I tried adding an icon from font awesome to my html code. The icon ' question circle 'shows up in the UI part but I can't set the size through the CSS. Also I can't change the color of the icon in CSS.

```
<label htmlFor='vaccine' className='labelField' >
 Preferred Vaccine 
 <i className="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
 </label><br></br>
                            
   

 .fa fa-question-circle{
      font-size: x-large;
      }
```

Comment: create a custom class and append it to `<i className="fa fa-question-circle your_class"></i>`

Answer (score 2):

Font Awesome has some dedicated components for ReactJS

Check this link: https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react

You can easily style your icons and set size:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon="faCoffee" size="2x" />
```

className:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon="faCoffee" className='myClassName' />
```

or many other props

Answer (score 1):

Simple do this ->

`<i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-2x"></i>`

or use these instead:

```
fa-xs;
fa-sm;
fa-lg;
fa-2x;
fa-3x;
fa-5x;
fa-7x;
fa-10x;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want a 5x icon size you need to pass it to the react class as `size`

```
// Font awesome pixel sizes relative to the multiplier. 
// 1x - 14px
// 2x - 28px
// 3x - 42px
// 4x - 56px
// 5x - 70px

<i className="fa fa-question-circle" size={70}></i>
```

if you notice it jumps by 14 each time

[from the github readme](https://github.com/gorangajic/react-icons#configuration) it shows everything is overridden inline. its rendering a svg so you cant use `5x` you have to use a pixel size